# Login Then POST

Tags: php, post, cookies, authentication

Its possible to create one php code to login using post and store the cookies?
Then using the cookies do another post?

If possible i would like a php code without showing nothing, maybe echo Post 1 OK echo Post 2 Ok

I found this code but it does not work

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://xxxxxxxx/login.php');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'username=xxxxxxx&password=xxxxxxxxx&submit=Login');
Curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
$store = Curl_exec ($ch);
curl_setopt ($ch. CURLOPT_URL, 'http://xxxxxx/postlink2.php');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'info1=xxxxxxx&info2=xxxxxx&info3=xxxxxxxxxx');
$content = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend finding out if the site has an API you can use instead of going this route, but yes, it is possible.  The following should work, though I haven't tested it:

```
$curl = curl_init('http://xxxxxxxx/login.php');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'username=xxxxxxx&password=xxxxxxxxx&submit=Login');
$response = curl_exec($curl);
preg_match('/^Set-Cookie: ([^;]*)/m', $response, $matches);
$cookie = $matches[1];
curl_close($curl);

$secondRequest = curl_init('http://xxxxxx/postlink2.php');
curl_setopt($secondRequest, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'info1=xxxxxxx&info2=xxxxxx&info3=xxxxxxxxxx');
curl_setopt($secondRequest, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($secondRequest, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$content = curl_exec($secondRequest);
curl_close($secondRequest);
```